# Apply transform computed at lower resolution to a higher resolution object

Tags: opencv, matrix, layout, transform, scale

I'm working on an iOS app that has to compute the transform matrix between consecutive real time video frames. I'm using OpenCV to compute optical flow and then find the affine matrix.

This process was working perfectly but was a little slow, so I'm now downsampling each frame to half its size before start processing it. The thing is, I have to later apply the transform to another video frames with the original resolution (double of the one for which I compute the matrix).

**My question is**: how should I apply the transform matrix I have computed for a frame at resolution X, to another frame with resolution 2X? I know I should "scale" the matrix somehow, but not sure how. I've tried multiplying the translation components of the matrix by 2, and this works almost perfectly (although I don't understand why), but depending on the transformation sometimes is not accurate.

One possible solution is to scale the frame to half its size, apply the transform and then scale it back to its original size, but this have a cost in performance, that's why I'm trying to compute a single matrix I can later use to transform the frame.

Answer (score 1):

If your use a homography from H_00 to H_22 then you have to apply a scale factor to H_00 and H_11.

I would recomend another workaround. After tracking or correspondenz estimation. If x0[n], y0[n] are your start points and x1[n] , y1[n] your end points multiply both with a scale factor an than run findHomography or getAffineMatrix. E.g. let w0=200 and h0=100 be the width and height of your frame you estimated the feautre correspondenzes with and w1=400 and h1=300 the frame you want to apply. Than sx=2 and sy=3 are the scale factors and x0[n] = x0[n] * sx and y0[n] = y0[n] * sy and x1[n] = x1[n] * sx , etc.